# Align Iframe with buttons

Tags: html, button, iframe

I´m trying to align an *iframe* with the social buttons.
This is my website:
http://kickads.mobi/test/spotify/

The thing is that I want to put the buttons right down the *iframe*, leaving the Spotify preview in a line and the buttons in another, but I don´t know how. I have tried with aboslute position and floating, but it wouldn´t work.
I want to put the three buttons in a line after the *iframe*.

How can I do it?
I have separated the buttons and the *iframe* in different divs.

Can you help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! At StackOverflow, we are helping developers to get stronger. However, we won't never let company get rid of them by requesting free jobs on this forum. So in order to distinct yourself from these sharks, show us some effort, pieces of code, some bugs, or other... And then we will help you! Please take the tour and read "What types of questions should I avoid asking?" [help/dont-ask], "What topics can I ask about here?" [help/on-topic] and [mcve]!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following CSS styling on the social div could achieve what I think you're asking for:

```
#social {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   min-height: 190px;
}
```

It will give you this output:

[image]

Comment: If I want to put the social at the bottom of the section, should I modify the min-height?

Comment: @CarlaPaludetto so from my understanding you would like the social div to be at the very bottom of the window? Rather than just below the iframe?